# How do I get Oauth.io to work with mobile browser full screen mode?

Tags: ios, oauth, fullscreen, oauth.io

I currently use oauth.io for login to fb, twitter, linked and instagram on a website application. Everything works fine accept for when the user hits the "Add to Home Screen" option and then uses the website by clicking on that home screen icon(fullscreen browser). I get a cross domain(I think)issue. I get this error right after login and no success function is run: "Unable to post message to http://www.example.com. Recipient has origin https://oauth.io."

Is there any reason that this only happens in the mobile fullscreen mode?